# What is the difference between php-fpm and php5-fpm

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I am currently using a cloud service from digitalOcean, and using centOS7.
I was trying to install php5-fpm, however this I was unable to find this package.
on `yum search php-fpm` I found out that there were 4 package such as.
       php-fpm
       php56-php-fpm

So what exactly is the difference between both of these. and which one should I install?
I am currently installing it with Nginx.

Regards

Comment: You need to install the PHP version you wish to use.

Comment: @JuliePelletier So does that mean `php-fpm` is the one for php version 1.x?

Comment: No.  It actually refers to the version considered to be the default for your repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the difference between php-fpm and php5-fpm?

Use the commands `yum info php-fpm` and `yum info php5-fpm` to look at the details of each package and then spot the differences. The packages may distinguish themselves in version,  originate from different repo's, the optional/additional packages available in that same repo etc.

> Which one should I install?

The one that best fits your needs.